The difference between する and つく with onomatopoeias (e.g. ざらざらする vs. ざらつく)
Taking a verb pair like ざらざらする and ざらつく, I want to know if in general the mimetic word affixed with つく is affixed with any practical differences in usage.
Here are examples of the verb pairs I am referring to:

ぐずぐずする・ぐずつく
ごたごたする・ごたつく
ごろごろする・ごろつく
ぎらぎらする・ぎらつく
ざわざわする・ざわつく
だぶだぶする・だぶつく
ドキドキする・どきつく
バタバタする・バタつく

The only thread I can think of are these potential tendencies:

つく version seems to be perhaps less versatile, or that the duplicated mimetic word is more emphatic.
Going back to the original example of ざらざらする and ざらつく, goo has this to say:

「ざらざら」は、特に手で触った感じについていうことが多い。
「ざらざら」は、「ざらざらした声」のように、ささくれて荒れているさまや、「土壁が ざらざらと崩れ落ちる」のように、粒状のものが一度に落ちるさまを表わすこともある。

ざらつく seems to mostly carry the meaning of becoming gritty, sandy, etc while ざらざら means those things but can also be used in the case of gritty voices.

In both the する and つく most meanings are shared, but one is more prominent than the other and vice versa.
For example, むかむかする can both mean to get queasy and to start getting mad, and ムカつく can mean both of those things too, but it seems むかむかする is most commonly used for queasiness and ムカつく more for getting angry. But I am not so sure about this considering むかむかする is pretty commonly used for both.


There's also I think a tendency for the つく version to be less common perhaps, with less meanings listed in dictionaries than the する version, like だぶだぶする and だぶつく (だぶだぶする seems more common so perhaps more versatile).
Basically, is there any way to make sense of the difference between mimetic words+する and their つく counterpart if they have one? Are there any specific patterns here? Does the addition of つく add any shared nuance between these verbs? If you compare the various forms a mimetic word might take like ガラッと and がらりと the difference seems small, but I feel verbs may be broader in their differences somehow.

「ドキドキする」は言うけど「どきつく」って初めて見ました・・（「ときめく」は聞きますが関係あるかは知りません。「～めく」と言えば、きらきらする・きらめく、ざわざわする・ざわめく、よろよろする・よろめく、などもありますね）

そうなんですか。でも、どうやら本当に存在しているみたいですよ。だから「つく」というのが何らかの補助動詞として無意識に使われている傾向があるってことなんじゃないですか。文法的な用語に詳しくないけど

「つく」は、接尾辞としての用法があるようですよ。デジタル大辞泉には、つく［接尾］《動詞五（四）段型活用。動詞「付く」から》擬声語・擬態語などに付いて、そのようなようすを示す状態である意を表す。「がた—・く」「ふら—・く」 とあります。

In many cases, you should remember the つく versions as distinct verbs with derivative meanings. For example, the most common meaning of だぶつく is "to be oversupplied; to be in glut", but it would be hard to predict this meaning from its original sense of ダブダブ. ガタガタする just means making rattling sounds, whereas がたつく usually also implies something is half broken (we even say ガタが来る). ムカつく is indeed more strongly associated with anger. Unfortunately, I think you have to remember these usages on a case-by-case basis.
On the other hand, there are cases where the two versions are basically interchangeable (ぐらぐらする/ぐらつく and ざわざわする/ざわつく). In such cases, the basic meanings are the same, but onomatopoeias are onomatopoeias, so they tend to sound colloquial and slightly informal. The つく versions have been established as verbs for many years, so they tend to be chosen in serious or formal writing.
